# Pointwise convergence implying uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am looking for a proof that if $\{f_n\}$ is pointwise convergent to $f$ on $[a,b]$ and $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and each $f_n$ is increasing then $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly convergent to $f$.

Thank you.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1209490/253359 may be this will help u

Comment: That's Dini theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem

Comment: Perhaps you also assume that $f_n$'s are continuous? The claim doesn't hold otherwise.

Comment: @Adayah take $f_n(x)=-|x|/n$ in [-1,1]. That is an increasing sequence which converges uniformly to 0 but $f'_n$'s are not continous

Comment: @LeonardoVannini First, I used the character ' as an apostrophe to separate a LaTeX expression from the suffix, not to denote a derivative - so I mean each $f_n$ has to be continuous, not $f_n'$. Sorry for the confusion. Second, you're giving an example where the additional hypothesis does not hold while the conclusion does. But I don't see what's that supposed to prove, since I claim the additional hypothesis is necessary for the result to hold in general, i.e. without it the theorem might fail (but does not have to), with it it might not.

Comment: @Adayah Sorry, you're right. I thaught you meant the sequence of the derivatives and so I show an example of a sequence of continoys function with discontinous derivative which converges uniformly.

Furthermore if with "$f_n$'s increasing" you mean increasing respect to the variable $x$ the result is true without continuity of $f_n$'s

Answer (score 1):

That result is known as Dini's theorem.

- Rudin's Principle of Mathematical Analysis: theorem 7.13
- Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem

---

Exists another "similar" result:

Let $(f_n)$ a sequence of function defined on $[a,b]$ and **increasing respect the variable**, if pointwise limit is continous then the convergence is uniformly.
Note that in this case continuity of $(f_n)$'s isn't required.

What are you looking for? What do you mean with "increasing"?